# How to use libcurl to get file size on ftp server?

Tags: libcurl

I'm trying to upload files to remote servers. Since some extra processing have to done on the files as the files uploaded, I have to use specified approach other than ftp to upload files. However, I want to get the uploaded file size through ftp, as it is the only way I can access the files.

Is there any way to get the file size using libcurl without uploading/downloading the files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you set `CURLOPT_NOBODY` (as in literally "no body") to `1L` when getting the URL, libcurl won't download the content, only give you meta data about the file.